# Blazor - Static Html file routing

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

Here I have a **static HTML file** (index.html) placed in a folder named `Test` inside `wwwroot`.

How can I configure the app to make it accessible at `/Test` address?
Currently seems I need to specify the whole address: "test/index.html"

Comment: do you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure` in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, it is there.

Comment: Do you use IIS?

Comment: tried `host:port/Test/some.html`?

Comment: @GuyatMercator This is the default Blazor hosting bundle shipped with the latest .net 5.0

Comment: @LeiYang Tried: https://localhost:44325/test/ and it is said "There is nothing at this address"

Comment: test/some.html,

Comment: @LeiYang Edited my question some minutes ago, and included that in the question. Yes test/index.html will bring the html page. (some.html & some2.html don't exist but show a blank pages.)

Comment: @Kasrak Just before `UseStaticFiles();`, please add `UseDefaultFiles();` and try again

Comment: @AmalK Nice catch! If you want make an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @Kasrak Just a minute, I'll write an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically look for the following files, when you route to a directory in `wwwroot`:

- *default.htm*
- *default.html*
- *index.htm*
- *index.html*

Just before `UseStaticFiles()` in the `Configure` method in *Startup.cs*, add a call to `UseDefaultFiles()`:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

If you want file names other than the four mentioned above, you can create an instance of `DefaultFilesOptions` and add the file names you want:

```
var options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("mycustomfilename.html");

app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

For more info, see [serving default documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-default-documents).

Also, if you want to allow directory browsing, you can replace both the above calls with:

```
app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);
```

The above combines `UseDefaultFiles()`, `UseStaticFiles()` and `UseDirectoryBrowser()`.

Comment: Thanks Amal, marked it. Not necessary but if the file doesn't have a default name, something like "Test.html" or "test1.html" or any other files (to be loaded on defined addresses), how can we address that? Any suggestion or good article about it?

Comment: @Kasrak You're welcome :). Please check the updated answer. You can create an instance of `DefaultFileOptions` and use its `Add()` method to configure more file names.